# SQL compare to identical tables copy value from certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, insert

I have two identical tables (x) and (y) (I made a backup from table x to table y) I deleted everything in table x to regenerate new rows (I added restmilk_3 as extra parameter).

Now my ID is new in table x (It moved because i added restmilk_3), so i want to copy the value from table y to x by name and RID (Recipe ID)

So how it looks like:

```
**table y**

ID - RID            - Name        - Value
1  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk_1  - cheese1
2  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk_2  - cheese3
3  - Cheese_rec_100 - milkamount  - 5000
..
100- Cheese_rec_100 - milkdensity - 0.46


**table x** (We added restmilk 3 as a new parameter):

ID - RID            - Name        - Value
1  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk_1  - NULL
2  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk_2  - NULL
3  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk 3  - NULL
4  - Cheese_rec_100 - milkamount  - NULL
..
100- Cheese_rec_100 - milkdensity - NULL


After the query:

ID - RID            - Name        - Value
1  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk_1  - cheese1
2  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk_2  - cheese3
3  - Cheese_rec_100 - restmilk 3  - NULL
4  - Cheese_rec_100 - milkamount  - 5000
..
100- Cheese_rec_100 - milkdensity - 0.46
```

So I can't use ID as key to copy the Value but I need to check if the RID and Name is equal from both tables.

I tryed alot of things but I dont have the skills/experience to solve this puzzle.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 
Database collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS
Compatability level: SQL Server 2012

I have all rights as administrator.

Example existing table:

```
ID  RID Version NodeID  Name    TagAddress  Value
854389  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _RestMilk14 -   0
854390  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _RestMilk15 -   0
854391  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _RestMilk16 -   0
854392  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _RestMilk17 -   0
854393  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _RestMilk18 -   0
854394  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _Starter1388Delay   -   240
854395  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _Starter1388Target  -   90
854396  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _Starter1389Delay   -   0
854397  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _Starter1389Target  -   0
854398  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _TransPercentageFat -   0,94
854399  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _TransPercentProtein    -   0,935
854400  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _VATPostWaterTempSP -   33,1
854401  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _VATRecipeNo    -   19
854402  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _WheyCreamLimit -   2
854403  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _AmountOfMilk   -   1000
854404  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _AverageWeightAt15D -   13,3
854405  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _CaCl2Delay -   600
854406  Cheese_Rec_00100    61  8   _CaCl2Target    -   0,1337
```

Comment: Seems like the old XY problem here. Why change the ID in table X? How did all the "Value" end up null in table Y if you copied all the data? Something not adding up. Unless you are using the table ID for the recipe order? That's not what the ID is for. You should have a separate column for ordering if that is necessary.

Comment: I needed to "regenerate" the rows to add the new parameter restmilk_3, so to do this I deleted everything in table x and regenerated the parameterlist with a existing program. That is why i made a copy of table x to y, so i can put back the information and than the operators have only to fill in the new parameter restmilk_3.

Comment: Why didn't the program add the new instruction as ID 101? Why would it replace ID 3 with a new ID? This is not good practice. Are there any other tables linked to this one by a foreign key? If so, aren't those keys now broken?

Comment: Hi Jacob, that is because the program is made to one time generate a table and than leave it alone like it is :) But now few years laters we need a extra parameter. This parameter table is made to copy to a PLC with a OPC server. I lake on skill to rebuild this part, so that is why i do it this way. Is there no solution for my question? If not i have to find a other way

Comment: It is possible, just trying to avoid your data being corrupt... Are all the values in the Name field unique for each RID?

Comment: Hello Jacob, yes it is! So the "key" IF table.x.RID == table.y.RID AND table.x.Name == table.y.Name then move value from table.y.value to table.x.value

I editted the first post with a example of the real table (part of it because i have to avoid sharing secrets :P )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check/ensure if RID and NAME columns are equal in table X and Y by using UNION ..

SELECT RID,Name FROM y 
  UNION 
  SELECT RID,Name FROM X

If number of rows returned are equal to number of rows in table X.. Then Update as you mentioned in your comments.

UPDATE X SET X.VALUE=Y.VALUE
  FROM X 
  INNER JOIN Y ON Y.RID=X.RID AND Y.NAME=X.NAME

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I try it tommorow, I will post my results.

Answer (score 0):

As final this is my code:

```
update [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter]

set 
    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].Value = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].Value,

    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].MaterialTagAddress = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].MaterialTagAddress,

    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].[Material_PLCID] = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].[Material_PLCID] ,

    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].[Material_SiteMaterialAlias] = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].[Material_SiteMaterialAlias],

    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].[Material_Name] = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].[Material_Name]  


From [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter] 


    INNER Join [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2] ON
    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].RID = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].RID

AND

    [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter_2].Name = [TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].Name

WHERE[TPMDB].[dbo].[RecipeNodeParameter].RID like '%cheese_rec_00100%'
```